# How to write a Loop that replaces occurrence of characters from a String?

Tags: java, regex, string

This is something I have been trying to do since morning but no luck so far.

> Without the use of **"regex"** or **replace()** of String, but only loop, write a method that replaces **occurance** of string from **parentString** with something else.

I was able to implement a version where `type char replaceWith` is to be replaced, but no luck if a `type String replaceWith` is to be replaced as in the template below.

```
public String replaceWith(String parentString, String occurrence, String replaceWith){
      String newString; //Initialize

      //loop through "parentString", 
      //find and replace "occurence" with "replaceWith"

 return newString;
}
```

Comment: You know you need to use a loop, so show us your loop.  How to do you find a string? how to you replace it? How about reading how `indexOf` works from the source

Comment: Hint: (assuming this is course work) try replacing `newString` with a `StringBuilder` and returning `newString.toString()` after looping over parentString

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wrote this fast solution:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{

public static String replaceWith(String parentString, String occurrence, String replaceWith){
      String newString = "";

      for(int i = 0; i <= parentString.length()-occurrence.length(); ++i) {
        boolean add = false;
        for(int j = 0; j < occurrence.length(); ++j) {
            if(parentString.charAt(i+j) != occurrence.charAt(j)) add = true;
        }
        if(add) {
            newString += parentString.charAt(i);
        } else {
            i += occurrence.length()-1;
            newString += replaceWith;
        }
      }

      return newString;
}

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(replaceWith("I replace banana, banana and some more banana", "banana", "apple"));
    }
}
```

You can see this working here: https://ideone.com/GwB7Ba
It outputs:

```
I replace apple, apple and some more apple
```

Comment: That was fast and smooth. Thanks

Comment: Also, I hope that you try to understand this code. I basically look at every parentString position and look if "occurrence" can start with there. If i find "occurrence" I add "replaceWith" to the string and continue where "occurrence" ended. Otherwise I just build up the "parentString".

Comment: It would be faster for large strings if you used a StringBuilder

Comment: So... `replaceWith("Hello World", "Hello", "World")` outputs `World W`. I don't think this is the correct solution. @Nexima360

Answer (score 1):

Use a string searching algorithm, that checks the characters of the occurrence against all the characters up to the length of occurrence. Something like this Rabin-Karp Algorithm

```
function NaiveSearch(string s[1..n], string pattern[1..m])
    for i from 1 to n-m+1
      for j from 1 to m
         if s[i+j-1] ≠ pattern[j]
            jump to next iteration of outer loop
       return i
    return not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
public String replace(String source, String target, String replacement) {
    int targetLength = target.length();

    int sourceLength = source.length();
    if (sourceLength < targetLength) {
        return source;
    }

    String result = source;

    for (int i = 0;  i< sourceLength - targetLength; i++) {
        String before = result.substring(0, i);
        String substring = result.substring(i, i+targetLength - 1);
        String after = result.substring(i + targetLength);
        if (substring.equals(target)) {
            result = before.concat(replacement).concat(after);
        } 
    }

    return  result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My quick solution was this. No guarantees all output is correct.

```
public static String replaceWith(String s, String find, String replace) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int findLength = find.length();
    int sourceLength = s.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < sourceLength; i++) {
        String nextSubstring;
        if (i + findLength >= sourceLength) {
            nextSubstring = s.substring(i);
        } else {
            nextSubstring = s.substring(i, i + findLength);
        }

        if (nextSubstring.equals(find)) {
            sb.append(replace);
            i += findLength - 1;
        } else {
            sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Sample test

```
replaceWith("Hello World", "Hello", "World") => "World World"
replaceWith("HelloHelloWorld", "Hello", "World") => "WorldWorldWorld"
replaceWith("I replace banana, banana and some more banana", "banana", "apple") => I replace apple, apple and some more apple
```